# SQL regular expression for date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch only date using regular expression in SQL Server. Below is my row value. I want to fetch only date part.

```
'JACKSONVILLE, FL                  2019-02-01 10:00:03 EST'
'JACKSONVILLE, FL       abc        2019-02-01 10:00:03 EST'
```

In this sequence data are stored in table row. length of the record may vary.Please suggest

Comment: which dbms you are using (mysql, postgresql, tsql, ...)?

Comment: Date or DateTime?

Comment: you wish to filter using regex or apply the regex on the select column, im not sure how you can do the latter

Comment: Avoid confusion and just never use the term "regex" when talking about SQL Server -- it doesn't support regexes, neither in the liberal sense of `grep` nor in the computer theoretical sense of a regular language. `LIKE` patterns support limited forms of wildcard matching, but they're strictly less powerful than proper regexes. The problem would be much easier to solve with actual regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server support for regular expressions isn't the best but I believe this will work

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 
      PATINDEX('%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]%', column),LEN(column))
```

Comment: length of records may vary.

Comment: @Tamojit Then describe that in your question. But will the date vary, if the format of the date is always the same and the date is always last in the record this should work?

Comment: Actually I am trying if any regular expression that find '2019' and fetch the date part, it will be better.

Comment: It's working Joakim. Thanks a lot. Is there any way to fetch only date part, not time?

Comment: @Tamojit Replace the last argument, LEN(), for SUBSTRING with 10

Answer (score 1):

`PATINDEX` can be used in combination with `SUBSTRING` to get the timestamp sub-string.

And if you want to convert it to a datetime type with a timezone, then something like  the Sql Snippet below could work.
Assuming those are all in the EST timezone.

```
select 

SUBSTRING(col, 
          PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%', col)
          ,23) as timestamp_string,

(CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), 
   SUBSTRING(col, 
             PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] EST%', col),
             19))
   AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time') as timestamp_string_as_datetime2

from 
(values 
 ('JACKSONVILLE, FL       2019-02-01 11:00:03 EST'),
 ('JACKSONVILLE, FL  abc  2019-02-01 12:00:03 EST cdf ')
) v(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the records have a fixed length it would be the best way to use left(...) and right(..)

```
select left(right('JACKSONVILLE, FL                  2019-02-01 10:00:03 EST', 23), 19)
```

Comment: records length may vary time by time

Answer (score 0):

sql sever does not support regex, the like pattern is basic support of pattern than regex but the below can check many patterns.
in this query all months are considered 31 days.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE 
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-0[0-9]-0[1-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-0[0-9]-[1-2][0-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-0[0-9]-3[0-1]%' OR
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-1[0-2]-0[1-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-1[0-2]-[1-2][0-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-1[0-2]-3[0-9]%' Or
```

if months or days can have on digit you should add this conditions also

```
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-0[1-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[1-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[1-2][0-9]%'  or
DateFild  LIKE '%[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-3[0-1]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a couple more 'or' clauses for a 2 digit month and 1 digit day. This is what I get:

```
DateFild  LIKE '0[0-9]-0[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '0[0-9]-[1-2][0-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '0[0-9]-3[0-1]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR
DateFild  LIKE '1[0-2]-0[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '1[0-2]-[1-2][0-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '1[0-2]-3[0-1]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]' Or
DateFild  LIKE '[1-9]-0[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '[1-9]-[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '[1-9]-[1-2][0-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '[1-9]-3[0-1]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or 
DateFild  LIKE '0[0-9]-[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'  or
DateFild  LIKE '1[0-2]-[1-9]-[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```